# Excel Index with Filter Formula Returning an Error

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

How do I resolve this error?  I am essentially taking values in column A and copying them to column F, but column F must populate automatically when new values are added to column A.  Thanks! (I have another formula that does something similar, but doesn't quite meet the requirement)

Comment: get rid of the INDEX wrapper,  INDEX is expecting a number return and FILTER is returning the values.  Just doe the FILTER part.

Comment: Or, you can do this `=TOCOL(A:A,1)` so it will keep adding new data in column F whenever there is new data in added in column A. If you dont have `TOCOL()` then do as said above by @ScottCraner Sir using only `=FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")` or, can do this one. `=LET(x,MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>"")),y,A1:INDEX(A:A,_x),FILTER(y,y<>""))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya TOCOL worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @Geek you can post this the solution as answer.